# TFS 2013 - Missing permission "View collection-level information"

Tags: visual-studio, security, tfs, permissions, tfs-2015

I'm administrator of a project in TFS 2013. I was trying to change permissions on different group from the web interface and for a mistake I changed the following permission on my group:

View collection-level information

Now if I go on the "Manage collection security and group membership" of the project, I get always this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, your account have no View collection-level information permission.

In this case, you will have no access to directly view and modify the permission to recover the permission.

To recover this permission, you can refer to the following methods:

1.You can check if there are other TFS administrators have the access to modify the permission. If yes, you can contact these users to help you recover the permission.

2.You can create a new local account and add the account to **Team Foundation Administrators** group in TFS console.

For example:

[image]

Then you can use the new admin account to login to TFS and recover the permission.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Server-level groups](https://github.com/tonyo/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/organizations/security/permissions.md#server-level-groups)